# Start-Transcript command in $profile saves unwanted text in each transcript

Tags: powershell

I have added a command to my profile to automatically save the transcript into a text file each time I start powershell as so:

```
start-transcript c:\scripts\$((Get-Date).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy-hh-mm-ss")).txt
```

but I can see that each time it saves the transcript it also saves this unwanted command info, is there anyway to not get these particular lines?

```
PS C:\Users\farha> @(Get-Command  -CommandType Cmdlet, Function, Script, ExternalScript, Workflow),@(get-module)

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        A:
Function        Add-BCDataCacheExtension                           1.0.0.0    BranchCache
Function        Add-BitLockerKeyProtector                          1.0.0.0    BitLocker
Function        Add-DnsClientNrptRule                              1.0.0.0    DnsClient
Function        Add-DtcClusterTMMapping                            1.0.0.0    MsDtc
Function        Add-EtwTraceProvider                               1.0.0.0    EventTracingManagement
Function        Add-InitiatorIdToMaskingSet                        2.0.0.0    Storage
Function        Add-MpPreference                                   1.0        Defender
Function        Add-NetEventNetworkAdapter                         1.0.0.0    NetEventPacketCapture
```

Answer (score 0):

The transcript cmdlet automatically creates a text file in your documents location by default.

Unless you are giving it a new name or a different location, there is no need to really change it. As for the extra stuff.

If you are starting this on load and you are using a profile (ISE or console) those command get ran and will show up in the transcript log.

If you don't want them in there then you must use the transcript cmdlet as the last line in your profile.

```
#region Begin Profile Configurations 
# your code here

#endregion End Profile Configurations 

# Start logging session
Start-Transcript
```

It will continue to log everything it can until you stop it or exit PowerShell.